# Most computationally efficient algorithm to create square sub-matrices of 1's along the diagonal of a large matrix, given size specs of sub-matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Given a list of numbers, for example [2, 4, 1, 3], create a square matrix of dimension sum(list) x sum(list) , where along the diagonals , there are square matrices of the sizes specified by the list. In the case of [2, 4, 1, 3] , that would result in

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

The method should generalize to any (positive) values in the list, and any length of list.

What I came up so far:

Brute force method: Create each sub matrix individually, and then concatenate all of them them. This becomes very inefficient of several of the size specifications are of size 1.

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if you actually needed anything more efficient than [`scipy.linalg.block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html).

Comment: Specifically, `scipy.linalg.block_diag(*(numpy.ones((x, x)) for x in [2, 4, 1, 3]))`

Comment: this solves it, if submitted as an answer I'll accept

Comment: `block_diag` creates a `zeros` array, and then copies each matrix to it using the right  slice.  It's a straight forward approach.  See the [source] link.

Comment: For up to size ~200x200 `repeat` seems fast: `np.identity(len(szs)).repeat(szs,1).repeat(szs,0)`

Comment: *"The method should generalize to any (positive) values in the list, and any length of list."* OK, but the relative efficiency of any method will likely depend on the distribution of the block sizes.  What sizes and number of blocks are you most interested in?

Comment: Goodquestion. I would say the most common number of items in my list would be from 64-256, and the sizes would most commonly range from 5-12